# I cannot create cloud service in Azure in North Central US regionhttp://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

At some point about a month ago we are not able to create Cloud Service (web/worker roles) in Azure in North Central US region in one of our subscriptions. Nothing is mentioned at official page here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services. We can do it in our old MSDN subscription, but cannot do it in new Pay-As-Go one.

Old portal doesn't list North Central in the list of available regions. New portal allows to select it but then some general error happens when we try to create the service. Cannot find any official information about it.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure service support question. This isn't something that can be answered here at StackOverflow. Perhaps open a billing support ticket? Note that every subscription is independent, and it's possible that a given subscription (such as your MSDN subscription) could be enabled for creating resources in a region list that differs from your other subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted Microsoft. Apparently, they try to unload North Central US datacenter as it is one of their oldest ones. We really wanted this particular, and they let us use it, just gave us access back.